# Hide div onload in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, blogs, blogger

HTML

```
<div id="b-navbar-fg">
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
   $(function(){
      $("#b-navbar-fg").hide() // try to hide google navigation bar
   });
</script>
```

This Function is executing in my google blogger page. But I am not able to hide this id on loading page.

[EXAMPLE PAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtwBn.png)

Comment: Is there any function to to call after the page loaded.

Comment: " $(function(){ "may be the issue. Try without that

Comment: jQuery(window).bind("pageshow", function() {//todo});

Comment: $(function(){ -> I am using this for page onload. if I set alert message inside function its working fine

Comment: Thanks for your help i ll try this one. -> jQuery(window).bind("pageshow", function() {//todo});

Answer (score 18):

You can use as in following :

**JS**

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('b-navbar-fg').style.display = 'none';
};
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#b-navbar-fg").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code :

```
window.onload = function() {
  $("#b-navbar-fg").hide();
};
```

If above code does not work, try this one :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#b-navbar-fg").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#div1').hide();
    $('#preview').on('click', function() {
            $('#div1').toggle(300);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
First Div Hide
</div>

<div id="div2">
Second Div
</div>

<div id="preview" style="color:#999999; font-size:14px">
<button>Click</button
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

if i use this on 2 element, only one is hided:
`window.onload = function(){ document.getElementById("start").style.display='none'; };`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).